# Custom font does't work only in Safari, but all other browsers work fine

Tags: css, fonts, safari, font-face

I'm developing website with GatsbyJS and using custom font called "Open Sans" for my design. I use font files and css file with @font-face, code is attached below:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Open Sans;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
  src: local('Open Sans Light'), local('OpenSans-Light'),
        url('open-sans-v17-latin_cyrillic-300.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('open-sans-v17-latin_cyrillic-300.woff') format('woff'),
        url('open-sans-v17-latin_cyrillic-300.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-display: swap;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: Open Sans;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  src: local('Open Sans Regular'), local('OpenSans-Regular'),
        url('open-sans-v17-latin_cyrillic-regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('open-sans-v17-latin_cyrillic-regular.woff') format('woff'),
        url('open-sans-v17-latin_cyrillic-regular.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-display: swap;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: Open Sans;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
  src: local('Open Sans Bold'), local('OpenSans-Bold'),
        url('open-sans-v17-latin_cyrillic-700.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('open-sans-v17-latin_cyrillic-700.woff') format('woff'),
        url('open-sans-v17-latin_cyrillic-700.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-display: swap;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: Open Sans;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-style: normal;
  src: local('Open Sans ExtraBold'), local('OpenSans-ExtraBold'),
        url('open-sans-v17-latin_cyrillic-800.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('open-sans-v17-latin_cyrillic-800.woff') format('woff'),
        url('open-sans-v17-latin_cyrillic-800.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-display: swap;
}
```

All work very nice in Chrome, Opera, Firefox but only Safari don't display Open Sans in the website... What could be the problem?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why bother with local font for Open Sans?  Who has that installed locally?  Did you try just using the google font to see if it renders properly? `<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,500,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

Comment: I want to make the website as autonomous as possible, if I understood your answer correctly. Do you suggest me to use @import for fonts from Google, right?

Comment: No.  You only need to add that `<link` to the head of your html.  No need for any @import  or @font-face in your css.  See [https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started).

Comment: Yes, it's good approach, but if I want to use local fonts what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure about the file paths?  try the full path rather than relative path to rule that out.  See [this reminder about relative paths](https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/).  Note: `src: local` only works if the user has the font installed on their computer.  Open Sans is not a standard installed font.